# Python type hinting - how to hint optional argument whose default is not None?

Tags: python, type-hinting

I am trying to implement PEP-484 in my Python 3 code for practice. While working on the following practice question, which looks like:

```
def fetch_n(what: str, n="all") -> List[obj]:
    query = "some sql string"
    if n == "all":
        # do the fetching
    elif isinstance(n, int):
        query = query + " LIMIT ?"
        # do the fetching
    else:
        raise ValueError
```

Is it possible to hint `n` in the function definition to be -- `const str or int`? If yes, how to do it?

I read the [cheat-sheet](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheat_sheet_py3.html) and currently I am using `from typing import Optional` and `n: Optional[int]` but its not working as desired.

Answer (score 5):

The `Optional[X]` is still only a type hint - it means `X or None`. Perhaps here you'd need an `Union` instead:

```
def fetch_n(what: str, n: Union[str, int] = "all") -> List[obj]:
    ...
```